# Why im getting exception error indexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 constructor i have :

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(keywords_path_file))
            {
                ListBoxLoadKeys(LocalyKeyWords, keywords_path_file);
            }
            else
            {
                fileExist = new StreamWriter(keywords_path_file);
                fileExist.Close();
                ListBoxLoadKeys(LocalyKeyWords, keywords_path_file);
            }
```

I use a breakpoint and see that the file is exist :

```
C:\Users\bout0_000\AppData\Local\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Keywords\Keywords.txt
```

The file content is:

```
http://www.walla.co.il,walla
http://www.cnet.com,cnet
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/29961.shtml,rotter
http://vanessawest.tripod.com/crimescenephotos.html,VanessaWest
http://rotter.net/forum/scoops1/45227.shtml,scoops
https://www.google.com/search?q=live+cameras,live camera
https://www.google.com/search?q=rape+images&oq=+images&aqs=chrome..69i57.1661j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8,hi
https://www.google.com/search?q=+images&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=GqotUv2kA4OftAae94DoAg&biw=951&bih=457&sei=oaotUtDqM8WbtAag3IFg#hl=en&q=+and+&tbm=isch&um=1,chud
http://www.test.com,test
```

The file contain 9 keys and keywords . Left side the keys right side the keywords.

Then its getting into this method:

```
private void ListBoxLoadKeys(Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary, string FileName)
        {
            List<string> urls = new List<string>();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName))
            {
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    int i = line.Count();
                    tokens = line.Split(',');
                    dictionary.Add(tokens[0], tokens.Skip(1).ToList());
                    data.Add("Url: " + tokens[0] + " --- " + "Localy KeyWord: " + tokens[1]);
                    urls.Add(tokens[0]);
                }
            }
            listBox1.DataSource = data;
            listBox1.Tag = urls;
        }
```

In the method when its getting o the line: listBox1.DataSource = data; its jumping and doing this event:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                label4.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                string startTag = "Url: ";
                string endTag = " ---";
                int startTagWidth = startTag.Length;
                int endTagWidth = endTag.Length;
                int index = 0;
                index = label4.Text.IndexOf(startTag, index);
                int start = index + startTagWidth;
                index = label4.Text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
                string g = label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);
                label4.Text = g;
                mainUrl = g;
            }
        }
```

In the end i see that data and listBox1.DataSource both contain 9 items.

After all this the program is running.
I see on the right in the listBox the items the keys and the keywords.
Once i click on one of the keys in the listBox1 im getting an exception on the line:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
```

In the listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event.

The exception is:

Index was outside the bounds of the array

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233080
  Message=Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ItemArray.GetItem(Int32 virtualIndex, Int32 stateMask)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.get_SelectedItem()
       at GatherLinks.Form1.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks-2\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\Form1.cs:line 543
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(IntPtr hWnd, Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmKillFocus(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

I know what the exception mean but what im getting it and how can i solve it ?

For example if i move first when running the program with the keys arrows up and down move between the keys in the listBox and then i click on one of them im not getting any exception.
The exception is show up when im running the program and right away first thing click with the mouse on one of the keys in the listBox.

Moving between them and then clicking on one of them is ok but clicking on one of them first thing make the exception.

EDIT**

I see now that before its going to the listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event to this event istBox1 mouse down:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control || ( Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control || e.Button == MouseButtons.Left))
            {
                listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
            }
        }
```

Doing this line:

```
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
```

Then back to the selectedindexchanged event and throw the exception on the line:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
```

That is also line number: 543

Comment: In debug mode, What is the line that handle this exception?

Comment: Unsure but `label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);` is suspicious.

Comment: line `543` is what? No idea which method can throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`, but in your code it happens inside `lisbox1_SelectedIndexChanged`, just put a breakpoint there and step by step check what is wrong.

Comment: It seems you're doing something multithreaded with `ListBox` control. Is it?

Comment: Updated my question i see now that frist its doing the listBox mousedown event then back to the selectedindexchanged event and then throw the exception.

Comment: btw, NEVER do this kind of thing in the Form ctor. Do it in Form_Load (add a handler). If you start doing databinding ontop based on items you've been messing with in the ctor you'll end up in a world of hurt. Additionally moving code out of the ctor will help the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control || ( Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control || e.Button == MouseButtons.Left))
  {
    listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
  }
  else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.One;
  }
}
```

Changing that property in the MouseDown event is, I think, destroying the window and getting it recreated again, which is messing with the internal information that fires during the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Simply comment out that code and decide during design time which SelectionMode the ListBox control should have.

You should also make sure you are getting a proper index value, example:

```
index = label4.Text.IndexOf(endTag, start + 1);
if (index > -1) {
  string g = label4.Text.Substring(start, index - start);
  label4.Text = g;
}
```

Comment: Not just "I think". It calls Control.RecreateHandle() in the SelectionMode setter!

Answer (score 2):

This is the decompiled code, in this case the `stateMask` here is the state mask that identifies a selected item.

```
public object GetItem(int virtualIndex, int stateMask)
{
  int actualIndex = this.GetActualIndex(virtualIndex, stateMask);
  if (actualIndex == -1)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
  else
    return this.entries[actualIndex].item;
}
```

So something must be changing because, as Sriram pointed out, there is the following check in the `SelectedItem` property:

```
public object SelectedItem
{
  get
  {
    if (this.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
      return this.SelectedItems[0];
    else
      return (object) null;
  }
}
```

So it somehow makes it past here, and then fails on the `GetItem`.  I suspect some threading tom-foolery.

Comment: Are you sure? This is the decompiled code `public object SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        if (this.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            return this.SelectedItems[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}`

Comment: Yes, that's a good point, I misread that originally.  So something must be changing between that check and the `GetItem` code.  Multi-threading maybe?

Comment: yes, I asked the same in comments. I suspect OP is doing modification in another thread

Comment: I updated my answer accordingly, although it's not really an answer anymore.  Thanks @SriramSakthivel

Comment: this is winform code, there can't be another thread modifying the controls because that would result in a different exception.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've had a little look at this and can conclude that the issue probably isn't with any of the code you've given to us but something else. I don't buy the suggestion that multi-threading is going on as multi-threading in WinForm is illegal and results in different exceptions.

What you need to do user2760148 is provide us with a [small but complete example](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/complete.html). Create a new project and implement the least code possible with the same result.

Your first step would be to hardcode the data for the listbox and just have that mouseDown event handler. Then slowly add your code back in until you find the problem. Chances are you'll find the problem yourself... at the very least you will find the step that causes the problem. At present there is too much "noise" in this example for us to find the specific problem easily.